Sanity groq query condition
 groq`
*[
  _type == 'pages' &&
  ( language == 'en-US' || language == "${lang}") &&
  slug.current == "${slug}" &&
  isHidden != true
][0]{

Hi everyone
Here I have other language pages I'm still only getting en-US pages i checked everything and it is fine still don't know what's wrong but if I remove || language == 'en-US' it will show me relative language pages can anyone help me

Try this: (language in ["en-us", "${lang}"])

@HairyHandKerchief23 If no page found for that specific lang then i want to show page from en-US as en-US is my default language and it has all pages

@HairyHandKerchief23 one question i dont understand when i'm using en-us its working but language im getting en-US why its still working?
